# Indy HTTP only sending numbers and stops at letters

Tags: http, delphi, indy, lazarus

I'm using Indy with Lazarus

Here is my code:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType  := 'text/plain' ;
IdHTTP1.Response.ContentType :=  'text/plain' ;
IdHTTP1.Response.Charset :=  'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'   ;
IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet:=    'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 '  ;
IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];      
IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.25.965:8541/rest/SearchCard('+MYCARD+')',Stream)  ;
```

If I start `MYCARD` with a letter, the server is picking up the full string. However, if I start with a number, it stops at the first letter.

```
MYCARD:= '12366854';     //works
```

```
MYCARD:= 'A125ASD555';   //Works
```

```
MYCARD:= '123YH963';   // The server only sees 123
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears to me like you're attempting to put javascript in the URL...

Answer (score 3):

First off, the two `Request` properties you are setting are meaningless in a `GET` request, and you should not be setting any `Response` properties at all.

```
// get rid of these assignments
//IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType  := 'text/plain' ;
//IdHTTP1.Response.ContentType :=  'text/plain' ;
//IdHTTP1.Response.Charset :=  'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'   ;
//IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet:=    'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 '  ;

IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];      
IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.25.965:8541/rest/SearchCard('+MYCARD+')', Stream);
```

Second, using the current version of Indy, I cannot reproduce your issue. `TIdHTTP.Get()` sends the specified URL as-is, it makes no assumptions about the characters in it (you are responsible for URL encoding). In my testing, `123YH963` works just fine.  Here is the actual HTP request being sent:

> GET /rest/SearchCard(**123YH963**) HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 192.168.25.965:8541
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

As you can see, the full `MYCARD` text is in the requested resource, as expected.  So any truncation must be happening on the server side, not in `TIdHTTP` itself.

Are you sure you are formatting the URL correctly to begin with? Are you sure it should actually be sent like this:

```
/rest/SearchCard(123YH963)
```

And not something more like these instead?

```
/rest/SearchCard%28123YH963%29
```

```
/rest/SearchCard/123YH963
```

```
/rest/SearchCard?param=123YH963
```

Comment: Changing the code to /rest/SearchCard/123YH963 did the trick!